# Setup mongodb for mongo-connector

Tags: mongodb

Did I use the right setup for [mongo-connector](https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector/blob/master/README.markdown)? I followed this steps [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/).

```
 PS C:\mongodb\bin> mongod --port 27017 --dbpath C:\data\db --replSet rs0
```

Then I start `C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe` and typed `rs.initiate()` and `rs.conf()`. If I check the status I get two errors:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.status()
Sat Jan 25 19:19:47.788 Socket say send() errno:10053 An established connection
was aborted by the software in your host machine. 127.0.0.1:27017
Sat Jan 25 19:19:47.803 Error: socket exception [SEND_ERROR] for 127.0.0.1:27017
 at src/mongo/shell/query.js:78
Sat Jan 25 19:19:47.803 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017
Sat Jan 25 19:19:47.819 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 ok
```

Comment: It looks like you may have had an open `mongo` shell which had a stale connection to the MongoDB server but was able to re-establish it. Does your `rs.status()` command return this error every time, or was this a one-off message?  What version of MongoDB is this?

Comment: `Mon Jan 27 08:58:05.531 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.9` now I get the msg `rs0:PRIMARY> rs.status(){ "set" : "rs0", "date" : ISODate("2014-01-27T07:58:11Z"), "myState" : 1,
        "members" : [ {"_id" : 0, "name" : "win-PC:27017", "health" : 1, "state" : 1, "stateStr" : "PRIMARY", "uptime" : 6, "optime" : Timestamp(1390553274, 1), "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-01-24T08:47:54Z"), "self" : true } ], "ok" : 1 }`, did I evrything right for using mongo-connector?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you now have a minimal replica set config (one node), so you should have an [`oplog`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) available for Mongo Connector. If you're not sure, try inserting a document into the `test` database and then check the oplog in the `mongo` shell: `db.getSiblingDB('local').oplog.rs.find()` should list a few operations.

Comment: Is `rs0:PRIMARY> db.getSiblingDB('local').oplog.rs.find()
{ "ts" : Timestamp(1390553274, 1), "h" : NumberLong(0), "v" : 2, "op" : "n", "ns
" : "", "o" : { "msg" : "initiating set" } }
{ "ts" : Timestamp(1390825042, 1), "h" : NumberLong("-9130147254844260335"), "v"
 : 2, "op" : "i", "ns" : "test.test", "o" : { "_id" : ObjectId("52e64e5271935141
6e453bb6"), "abc" : 1 } }` what you are expected? If I want to use now mongo-connector to connect mongodb with solr the command `python mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:8983/solr -d ./doc_managers/solr_doc_manager.py` should work?

Comment: Yes, that looks as expected. You have entries appearing in the oplog and the second one with `"op":"i"` is your test insert. You should be set to use mongo-connector now.